# How to grab facebook page feed?

Tags: plugins, feed, facebook

Hey all, i'm using the plugin [wp-Lifestream](http://www.enthropia.com/labs/wp-lifestream/) in its 0.99.9.6 version (the 0.99.9.8-BETAdoesnt work for me) and i was wondering if it was possible to associate a fb page feed rather than a profile feed. So far i didnt find any answer to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably would need to contact that plugin author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about subscribing to a page's *wall* (not notifications feed), then yes, you can do that.

To find the feed for the wall, the easiest thing is to visit the target Facebook page in Firefox. Click the RSS icon in the address bar and choose "Subscribe to THE PAGE NAME". This will bring you to the actual feed. Copy the URL of the feed, and set it up as a new Facebook feed in your Lifestream settings (Lifestream > Feeds > Add a Feed > Facebook). And you're done.

The reason you can't subscribe to a page's notifications feed is that there is no such thing. Pages are connected to user accounts, and as such they don't have notifications feeds of their own. If you do see a notifications feed while you're administering a Facebook page, it's the feed of the administering user, not of the page itself.

Comment: Dude you rock! Works just fine, thanks a lot for the solution and the infos.

Comment: @kevin No problemo!

Answer (score 1):

FYI everyone, it looks like with the new profile for fan pages - there's no longer an RSS feed available. My RSS has broken, and there's no longer the RSS icon mentioned in Firefox.

When I look at an old profile page, it still appears, but the new profile page has been upgraded and this has been removed.

My assumption is they are trying to get everyone to use their official Recent Activity widget.

FYI

Comment: Good call Bethany. Freaking Facebook! They're constantly changing things.

Comment: I just checked the site using this plugin, seems to still be ok.